# Remove a shape on click with CreateJS

Tags: javascript, createjs, easeljs

How do you remove only the shape that's in CreateJS?  For my example, I have created a few squares with a function called `createSquare`.  My goal is to have a function, or a click event, that removes only the square that is clicked.

I have tried event listeners and on click, and have had no luck.  I have commented out the code that I tried to use.

[Here is a link to a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/w1vssodr/1/)

JS is as follows:

```
var canvas;
var stage;
var square;

function init() {   
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
}

function createSquare(){
    square = new createjs.Shape();
    square.graphics.beginFill("red").drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50)
    square.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
        square.y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
    stage.addChild(square);
    stage.update();
}

// This code should remove the squares
/*
square.on("click", function(evt) {
    stage.removeChild(this);
});
*/

window.onload = init();

createSquare();
createSquare();
createSquare();
createSquare();
createSquare();
createSquare();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event handlers in CreateJS are passed an [event object](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Event.html). Mouse events receive a [MouseEvent](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/MouseEvent.html).

The target of the event will be what was clicked on.

```
square.on("click", function(evt) {
    stage.removeChild(evt.target);
    stage.update();
});
```

You will need to add the listener to each square when it is created.

Alternatively, you could listen to the stage one time.

```
stage.on("click", function(evt) {
    stage.removeChild(evt.target);
    stage.update();
});
```

Comment: This makes sense and clears up my confusion.  If I add other shapes, would adding the event to each square be the best solution?  For example, what if I want to do slightly different events for a square and a circle?  Fiddle of your other solution https://jsfiddle.net/w1vssodr/5/

Comment: I would recommend a single event handler. You could pretty easily throw a property onto the shape that indicates what it is, and check that in the click handler. Here is an updated fiddle showing how squares get removed, and circles decrease in alpha. https://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/w1vssodr/6/